# Not able to launch VMware Player

Tags: gcc, vmware-player

```
Installing VMware Player 6.0.6
configuring...
[#########################################################] 100%
Installation was successful.
root@shirishnag:/home/shirishnag/Desktop#vmware-installer -l
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Product Name    Product Version
==============  ================
vmware-player   6.0.6.2700073
root@shirishnag:/home/shirishnag/Desktop#
```

I'm not able to launch VMware Player due to `No protocol specified` error asking for GNU C compiler gcc version 7.2.0 was not found.

Comment: please add your command you used in order to install it because there are different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try the graphical installation method.

1. Therefore go to the vmware website and download the bundle of your
   choice: [wm ware: all downloads](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads)
2. Then execute the script you just downloaded in a terminal: eg: `sudo sh VMware-Player-12.5.1-yyy.x86_64.bundle` (VMware-Player-12.5.1-yyy.x86_64.bundle has to be the path to your downloaded file and can also be: `User/Downloads/VMware-Player-12.5.1-yyy.x86_64.bundle`)
3. Follow the instructions in the installation manager
4. To start it, type `vmplayer` in a terminal.

It is possible that even with this installation procedure you cannot launch it. Before giving more detailed information about this case, please try to update your version (even you just downloaded it). You can update your kernel with `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` within a terminal.

Good luck and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!